# Using a JSON key as a lookup in JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have some JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "itmVarModel": {
        "menuItemMap": {
            "0": {
                "matchingVariationIds": [1234],
                "displayName": "4 GB"
            },
            "1": {
                "matchingVariationIds": [5678],
                "displayName": "16 GB"
            }
        },
        "itemVariationsMap": {
            "5678": {
                "price": "GBP 62.99",
                "variationId": 5678
            },
            "1234": {
                "price": "GBP 15.00",
                "variationId": 1234
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to extract the name and price so that it looks like this:

```
{
  "itemname": "16 GB",
  "itemprice": "GBP 62.99"
}
{
  "itemname": "4 GB",
  "itemprice": "GBP 15.00"
}
```

I've just come across JQ which looks perfect for the job but the nearest I have got is:

```
[.itmVarModel.menuItemMap[].matchingVariationIds[]] as $names | {itemname: .itmVarModel.menuItemMap[].displayName, itemprice: .itmVarModel.itemVariationsMap."$names".price}
```

I am struggling with the syntax and don't really know what I am doing tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to keep `itemVariationsMap` in a variable, and retrieve item prices from there; not the other way around.

```
.itmVarModel
| .itemVariationsMap as $m
| .menuItemMap[]
| { itemname: .displayName, itemprice: $m["\(.matchingVariationIds[0])"].price }
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/2PFrnZOvJW)</sup>

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks ever so much. I would not have thought of reversing it